# Date coming out, not in the manner expected

Tags: javascript, java, html, json

Using Java servlet to build a piece of HTML and delivering it with a JsonPrimitive to show in a dialogue, (apologies for the scruffiness) as below;

```
 ja = new JsonPrimitive(
"<a href='#' onclick='return showDueDateUpdateDialogue(" + invoice.invoice_no + ", new String("+ sdfdate.format(invoice.invoice_due) +"));'>
<img border='0' class='tableImage' src='/Support/Images/Icons/application_edit.png' alt='Update due date' title='Update due date'/></a>");
```

This works well for all other values, but because I'm setting the date format as below;

```
SimpleDateFormat sdfdate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

The resulting date string from the function `showDueDateUpdateDialogue(in_no, date)` is read out in the console as;

54003, 0.0001983143282102132

I'm guessing that this is because the browser is reading 22/01/2019 as an equation. But I really just need the string value 22/01/2019.

How do I get that value, instead of the sum of 22/01/2019?

I've tried with and without `new String()`, but apart from that, have no idea how to fix.

Any ideas would be massively helpful, thank you.

Comment: this is not enough code. show us implementation of `showDueDateUpdateDialogue()`

Comment: By the way, your "sdfdate.format" leads me think you are using the troublesome old date-time classes such as `SimpleDateFormat` that are now legacy, supplanted by the *java.time* classes. You must post more information and code to get a good Answer. But please search Stack Overflow before posting, as your issue has likely been covered already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try surrounding your date inside a " " ?

```
ja = new JsonPrimitive(
"<a href='#' onclick='return showDueDateUpdateDialogue(" + invoice.invoice_no + ", \""+ sdfdate.format(invoice.invoice_due) +"\");'>
<img border='0' class='tableImage' src='/Support/Images/Icons/application_edit.png' alt='Update due date' title='Update due date'/></a>");
```